# jQuery in WordPress - Font Awesome Invert on mouseenter and mouseleave events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, font-awesome

I'm trying to add a very basic little jQuery script to a WordPress site which adds the fa-invert Font Awesome class to an icon on event mouseenter and then removes the class on mouseleave.

Here is my little script:

```
//Jquery Script to invert colour of icons on hover

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#IconHover").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass("fa-invert");
    });
    $("#IconHover").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("fa-invert");
    });
};
```

I've added this script to my function.php file as follows and it appears to be running fine when I load the page:

```
//include IconHover.js script
wp_enqueue_script('IconHover', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/IconHover.js', array('jquery'));
```

Now I've added the id of IconHover to my fa-twitter-square icon in the footer of the page but it doesn't seem to be inverting the colours on mouseenter.

Does anyone have any thought on why this may be? I've been looking at as many resources and examples of people doing similar things and I think that I am implementing the little bit of jQuery correctly within WordPress.

The site can be viewed here: http://dariusdevas.com/wp/?page_id=2

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated! :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its `fa-inverse`

that is it, following is working code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#IconHover").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass("fa-inverse");
    });
    $("#IconHover").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("fa-inverse");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting my typo! The little script works and I can't tell you how stoked and satisfied I am! It's a very simple little bit of code, but for me it is the first time that I have done something like this and for it to actually work! Very chuffed. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code one is due to deprecation, the other is a typo.

This is what it looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#IconHover").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass("fa-invert");
    });
    $("#IconHover").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("fa-invert");
    });
};
```

This is what it should look like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#IconHover").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass("fa-invert");
    });
    $("#IconHover").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("fa-invert");
    });
});
```

Also other than your bit of supplied code in your jquery there is a line of code that is deprecated this is:

```
event.returnValue
```

This needs to be changed to:

```
event.preventDefault
```